# Spring Boot Application Shutdown in Linux after few minutes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, shutdown

We have a sprint boot application working fine with JDK8, we have recently upgraded to JDK11 and spring boot version 2.2.8. The application is working fine in local (Windows 10). When we promote to EC2 instances with CentOS Linux application comes up fine and after few minutes getting shut down by itself without throwing any error in the log.

**Here are the messages we see in logs**

```
2020-06-19 12:06:34 [SpringContextShutdownHook] DEBUG o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose 1006 - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.A
nnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@37f1104d, started on Fri Jun 19 12:00:37 EDT 2020                                                           
2020-06-19 12:06:34 [SpringContextShutdownHook] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop 369 - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647          
2020-06-19 12:06:34 [SpringContextShutdownHook] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.lambda$doStop$2 242 - Bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' complete
d its stop procedure                                                                                                                                          
2020-06-19 12:06:34 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  o.s.s.c.ExecutorConfigurationSupport.shutdown 218 - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecut
or'                                                                                                                                                           
2020-06-19 12:06:34 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close 350 - OraclePool - Shutdown initiated...                       
2020-06-19 12:06:34 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close 352 - OraclePool - Shutdown completed.                         
2020-06-19 12:06:34 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  o.s.o.j.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.destroy 598 - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence 
unit 'default'                                                                                                                                                
2020-06-19 12:06:34 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close 350 - RDSPostgreSQLPool - Shutdown initiated...                
2020-06-19 12:06:34 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close 352 - RDSPostgreSQLPool - Shutdown completed.
```

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxxx.brm</groupId>
    <artifactId>marketshare</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>marketshare</name>
    <description>Springboot application for Marketshare application</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <swagger.version>2.7.0</swagger.version>
        <spring.security.core.version>5.3.1.RELEASE</spring.security.core.version>
        <hikaricp.version>3.2.0</hikaricp.version>
        <jwt.version>0.7.0</jwt.version>
        <org.postgresql.version>42.2.12</org.postgresql.version>
        <net.sf.ehcache.version>2.10.4</net.sf.ehcache.version>
        <com.h2database.version>1.3.176</com.h2database.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.9</jackson.version>
        <jackson-core.version>2.10.0</jackson-core.version>
        <org.snakeyaml.version>1.25</org.snakeyaml.version>
        <org.json.version>20190722</org.json.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.2.0</junit.jupiter.version>
        <jmockit.version>1.22</jmockit.version>
        <mockito.core.version>2.23.0</mockito.core.version>
        <dom4j.version>2.0.3</dom4j.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>${com.h2database.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <version>${org.snakeyaml.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.29</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                <version>${hikaricp.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dom4j/dom4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>${dom4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${org.json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ssm</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.184</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.5</version>
          <classifier>runtime</classifier>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>${jmockit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>xxx-maven-group</id>
            <name>xxx Maven Group</name>
            <url>https://xxxartifactory.jfrog.io/xxxartifactory/xxx-maven-group/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>xxx-maven-group</id>
            <name>xxx Maven Group</name>
            <url>https://xxxartifactory.jfrog.io/xxxartifactory/xxx-maven-group/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.21.0</version>
                    <dependencies>
                      <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.21.0</version>
                      </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>enforce-bytecode-version</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <enforceBytecodeVersion>
                                        <minJdkVersion>1.8</minJdkVersion>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>org.midrot.jbcrypt</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </enforceBytecodeVersion>
                                </rules>
                                <fail>true</fail>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0-beta-5</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-instrument</id>
                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>instrument</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
             </plugin>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: how do you launch your application ? with a service (systemctl) ?

Comment: yes, we start the application using the service systemctl. " sudo systemctl start marketshare" is the command we use to start the service.